# Get multiple columns with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all the columns with NULL values. That's what I'm using:

```
SELECT Customers_Name, Customers_LastName
FROM customers
WHERE (SELECT * FROM customers) IS NULL;
```

I get this error:

> Operand should contains 1 columns(s)

Whats the right way to do it ?

That's the question I'm asked to do :

Any Blanks. For each row retrieved, show all customers that have a blank in at least one of its columns. Sort from Z to A on last name then Z to A on first name.

Thank you to help, I'm new to coding.

Comment: A blank is usually considered the character ' '. NULL is a different thing. Whichever you are looking for, you'll have to check each column, e.g. `where colx like '% %' or coly like '% %' or colz like '% %'`. What is your DBMS? SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS. Is it MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ...

Comment: It's MySQL. There is like 9 columns, should I put all the names columns with ''is null'' or there's a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: No, there ain't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list each column explicitly:

```
SELECT Customers_Name, Customers_LastName
FROM customers
WHERE Customers_Name IS NULL OR Customers_LastName IS NULL;
```

Comment: If I have 9 columns, I should list each of them right? Thank you

Comment: @Jamalha889 . . . Yes.  You need to list each column separately.